# C - malloc allocating too much memory

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

running int a strange scenario where malloc is allocating more memory than I ask for:

```
void function (int array [], int numberOfElements) {

int *secondArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfElements/2);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements / 2; i++) {
    secondArray[i] = array[i];
  }
}
```

Let's say array is a some 10 numbers. When I print out secondArray after the above code, I get:

[image]

so first of all, the array should be 5 elements. But second, why the 0's in the end? I'm mallocing only space for 10/2 = 5 ints.

EDIT:

printing code:

```
for (int d = 0; d < numberOfElements; d++) {
   printf("%i ", secondArray[d]);
}
```

hmm I might have just answered my own question here, I'm guessing it's the printing beyond secondArray that shows 0, not the array itself.

-

Actually, the problem is that I was also not doing this:

```
secondArray[numberOfElements] = '\0';
```

That is why it was printing beyond.

Comment: Since you don't show the printing code, we can only guess.  A plausible guess is that you print `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)` instead of dividing by 2.  You are then invoking undefined behaviour and anything is permissible — including showing the answer you got.

Comment: I'll add the printing code

Comment: I might have answered my own question

Comment: Where does `n` come from?

Comment: sorry, n = numberOfElements

Comment: You're are just printing additional 5 memory location contents which you doesn't own leading to undefined behavior when you try accessing them.

Comment: n should be numberOfElements/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` is actually allocating exactly the right amount.

However, you're accessing memory beyond the allocation.

What exists there is completely undefined and could really be anything.

In your case, it was one "junk" number and four zeroes.

Comment: so how do I know what was allocated and what is undefined?

Comment: The amount allocated is no less than you ask `malloc` for. Accessing anything beyond that is undefined behavior and may have indeterminate values (if it doesn't outright crash).

Comment: No, I mean: suppose I don't have a way to keep track of the memory I allocated. Is there a way to get the amount of memory allocated?

Comment: That depends on who you are in this context: you can ask the system how much (heap) memory it's allocated for a given process, or attempt to probe your own memory status via `/proc/self` entries (on Linux, similar mechanisms exist for other OSes). None of these things will tell you whether a particular memory access is safe ahead of time, though -- the only way to reliably access heap memory is to allocate it yourself (with a size that you know) and index within that range.

Answer (score 0):

You are just lucky. Malloc can and sometimes does ask from more memory off the OS - Taking into account paging. Sometimes it does not even need to ask the OS for memory as it has asked for extra earlier. Therefore the malloc could ask for a page of memory - more that enough to satisfy your request and the extra memory happens to be filled with zeros.

You are in the land of undefined behaviour. So all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** its print 0 0 0 0 because in C no array bound if you define your array 
 * size is 4 but 
 * you want to store data more than array size you can store so you print your 
 * array.
 * for(i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) its give data and 0 also because you 
 * store the data 
 * only 5 position but you print it max size so it give you 0 0 0 
 */
    int *secondArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfElements/2); // no matter either use it or
    int *secondArray = malloc(sizeof(int));
    // ^^^ this will take same memory
```